# Column height matching automatically its width, using CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

How to make that a column using `flexbox` has a height which automatically/dynamically matches its width?

```css
#container { display: flex; width: 500px;   flex-direction: row; }
#a { background-color: red; width: 50%; }
#b { background-color: blue; width: 50%; height: 50%; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="a">
Hello
</div>
<div id="b">
This div should be square, its height should automatically match its width, and text vertically centered
</div>
</div>
```

Note: I don't want to use the `aspect-ratio` property which is too young (not support on enough browsers for my project) nor the similar solutions of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css), but with `flexbox`, as mentioned on top. Also this linked question does not consider the vertical alignement either.

Comment: You could use grid with aspect ratio

Comment: @DreamTeK Thanks! Can you give an example code snippet in an answer?

Comment: Haha yes @DreamTeK. Could you paste a jsfiddle? Grid is ok but not https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio which is not supported enough for my project. Thanks!

Comment: IE11 letting you down? Would the suggestion in the linked post not be suitable? If not we can reopen yours.

Comment: No it's not supported for Firefox or Chrome < 2020. This is too young for my project.

Comment: What about the post linked as duplicate?

Comment: @DreamTeK There is no suitable solution with `flexbox`, all the rest of the website is already done with `display: flex;` so I need to keep this.

Comment: Without support for latest css I can only suggest falling back to Javascript. Flexbox is designed to be one dimensional array, it doesn't support two dimensions very well thats why `grid` was created.